# Windows 10: How to make the taskbar dark without chosing dark colour mode

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, colors, display-settings

I don't think I had dark mode till a couple of days back. But my taskbar wasn't white in colour - I was some darker colour.

While trying to change some setting yesterday, I may have accidentally changed something by which my task bar became white

This is what my taskbar looks like now
[image: This is what my taskbar looks like now]

Looking at the settings, I see that the only way I can change the task bar colour is by choosing dark mode & then use accent colour for the taskbar.

Because when you are in a light colour mode, then the use accent colour for Taskbar option is greyed out.

I am pretty sure I didn't have dark mode earlier & I didn't have a white taskbar.

Is there any way to go back to that?

I am running Windows 10 Version 21H2 (OS Build 19044.2251)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the taskbar and apps to be different colors, you can use Custom color instead of Dark or Light.

Then you can Choose your default Windows mode as Dark. Choose your default app mode as light.

You can also use accent color again and apply it to the surfaces you choose.

[image: Custom color]